# How can I reshape a data.table when the order of the registers determines the category?

Tags: r, data.table, categories, reshape

Let's say I have the following data table:

```
dt=data.table(type=c('big','medium','small','small'
                     ,'medium','small','small'
                     ,'big','medium','small','small')
             ,category=letters[1:11])

      type category
 1:    big        a
 2: medium        b
 3:  small        c
 4:  small        d
 5: medium        e
 6:  small        f
 7:  small        g
 8:    big        h
 9: medium        i
10:  small        j
11:  small        k
```

In this case I have a category hierarchy: the 'big' type is the same for all rows until a following 'big' type is seen. And the behavior is the same for every type.

The reshape I want must give me the following:

```
dt=data.table(type=c('big','medium','small','small'
                     ,'medium','small','small'
                     ,'big','medium','small','small')
              ,category=letters[1:11])


   big medium small
1:   a      b     c
2:   a      b     d
3:   a      e     f
4:   a      e     g
5:   h      i     j
6:   h      i     k
```

As you can see each category only changes when a register of the same category is found, the order is important to set this categories.

Do you think there is a way to do this without using a for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an approach that you can use. You'll need `na.locf` from "zoo":

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)
```

First, we need to figure out the final rows. To do this, we need to explicitly define what the order of the types is, as you can start from the same `dt` and get different results, if the order is changed (that's what the `match` part does). Once you have the numeric order, if the diff is less than or equal to zero, that means it's going to be a new row in the new table:

```
dt[, rid := match(type, c('big', 'medium', 'small'))][, row := cumsum(diff(c(0, rid)) <= 0)]
```

This is what the data looks like now:

```
dt
#      type category rid row
# 1:    big        a   1   0
# 2: medium        b   2   0
# 3:  small        c   3   0
# 4:  small        d   3   1
# 5: medium        e   2   2
# 6:  small        f   3   2
# 7:  small        g   3   3
# 8:    big        h   1   4
# 9: medium        i   2   4
#10:  small        j   3   4
#11:  small        k   3   5
```

Here it is in the form you've requested:

```
na.locf(dcast(dt, row ~ type, value.var = "category"))
#    row big medium small
# 1:   0   a      b     c
# 2:   1   a      b     d
# 3:   2   a      e     f
# 4:   3   a      e     g
# 5:   4   h      i     j
# 6:   5   h      i     k
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys!... :)... I wonder how do you manage to come up with those answers, is it like experience or just talent?... what kind of backgrounds do you have?